# sql trigger-how to trigger an insert that update another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables named `CustomerGoods`(with column `quantity`) and `Stock`(with column `Availablequantity`). I want a trigger to occur when I insert into the `CustomerGoods` so that the quantity is added into `Availablequantity` in the `Stock` table.

Comment: I want a pony. Show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I want free pizza and beer. (Was there a question in there? Or were you just giving a status report.)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided proper and to the point problem, but as per my understanding from what you have written.

Please try this.

```
   CREATE
        TRIGGER `AvailablequantityTrig` AFTER INSERT ON `CustomerGoods` 
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    UPDATE Availablequantity set quantity=quantity+1 where GoodsID = NEW.id;

    END;
```

Here NEW.id is the id of goods and GoodsID is the id of goods in Availability table..

Please change your column names as required..

Thanks.